# как правильно вернуть массив?

Tags: javascript

```js
function double(value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    value.forEach(function(item) {
      return item * 2
    })
  }
  return value * 2;
}
console.log(double(2)); // 4
console.log(double([1, 2, 3])); // NaN
```

Comment: `value.map(v => v*2)` обычно для подобных целей используют

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function double(value) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {       
        return value.map(function(item) { // retun value.map(item => item * 2);
            return item * 2               //
        })                                //
    }   
    return value * 2;
}
console.log(double(2)); // 4
console.log(double([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция может передавать саму себя в map:

```js
function double(val) {
  return Array.isArray(val) ? val.map(double) : val * 2;
}

console.log(double(2));
console.log(double([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(double([1, [2, [3]]]));
```

`map()` в свою очередь вызовет её для каждого элемента массва, передавая его в виде первого аргумента функции (val). Если он оказался числом, `Array.isArray(val)` будет false, вернется `val * 2`

Приятная побочка: Будет умножать числа любой вложенности...